# Move one object in collection of objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Here is the scenario, I have these objects. Let's assume that this is a `User`:

The object came from:

```
@user = User.all
```

User Object

```
[<#User id: 1, firstname: "John", lastname: "Pond">,<#User id: 2, firstname: "Paul", lastname: "Rich">,<#User id: 3, firstname: "Jasmine", lastname: "Ong">]
```

How can I move one object up, for example I want to move `User.id == 2`? The result I want is shown below.

```
[<#User id: 2, firstname: "Paul", lastname: "Rich">,<#User id: 1, firstname: "John", lastname: "Pond">,<#User id: 3, firstname: "Jasmine", lastname: "Ong">]
```

Comment: Do you want the result in `ActiveRecord Relation Object` or converting it into an `Array` is ok?

Comment: I already solve the question. I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already got the answer. Here is what I made to made my question above worked.

```
@users = User.all
user_ids = User.pluck(:id)
user_ids.delete(2)
new_user_ids = [2]

user_ids.each do |id|
  new_user_ids << id
end

@users.sort_by { |user| new_user_ids.index(user.id) }
```

And this made perfect!

Answer (score -1):

We can also do it in a way like this:

Add a new method to Array. lib/rails_extensions.rb

```
class Array

  def swap!(a, b = a - 1)
           self[a], self[b] = self[b], self[a]
      self
  end

end
```

Then add this in config/environment.rb

```
require 'rails_extensions'
```

So we can use the method `swap!` for arrays and it will swap the object with the one before it. We can do something like this:

```
@users = User.all #[<#User id: 1>, <#User id: 2>]
user_id = @users.rindex {|user| user.id == 2}
@users = @users.swap!(user_id) #[<#User id: 2>, <#User id: 1>]
```

Comment: You are just swapping the object. And your code is not flexible. You have only 2 in an object. What if I have more that 100? You mean I modify the swap! method? My answer below is just enough.

Comment: Your question is about move one object up? Well if you want more flexibility why not just change the arg `b = a - 1` to `b`, so we can swap to whichever index we want?

Answer (score -1):

is this too ugly?

```
hash = [{ id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
hash.unshift(hash.delete(hash.select {|h| h[:id] == 2 }.first))
=> [{:id=>2}, {:id=>1}, {:id=>3}]
```

Comment: Not sorting an id, it's the whole User object in collection of objects.